# Sprite-kit How to pass integer value to next scene

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, skscene

I have 2 scenes `GameScene` and `GameLostScene`, in `GameLostScene` I created highScore but I don't know how to get current score from `GameScene`. Then I try to print score with `NSLog` I can see what value is not correct, what should I do to make it right?

`GameScene` method

```
 -(void) gameLost {

    SKScene *nextScene = [[GameLostScene alloc] initWithSize:self.size ];
    SKTransition *doors = [ SKTransition fadeWithDuration:1.0];
    NSLog(@"%ld", self.currentScore);
    [self.view presentScene:nextScene transition:doors];
}
```

GameLostScene

```
GameScene *gameScene;
long score = gameScene.currentScore;
NSLog(@"%ld", score);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your do not find your score data important or sensitive use `NSUserDefaults`

**First scene:**

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setInteger:yourScore forKey:@"HighScore"];
```

**Second scene:**

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
yourScore = [defaults integerForKey:@"HighScore"]
```

This will also store your score.

**Or you can just pass the data through scenes.**

In the FirstScene
In your .m file declare:

```
static NSInteger staticScore;
```

Create class method and return this value:

```
+ (NSInteger) passScore {
   return staticScore;
}
```

In another scene `#import` this class and get value like this:

```
[FirstScene passScore];
```

Comment: I already have highscore working correctly, I need to know what score was before you lost :)

Comment: Second part of my answer is about that how you pass that score to your second screen.

Comment: I can't understand, i whant to pass my Score to next scene, how should i declare it and where in my GameScene, and how i should access it in my GameLostScene?

Comment: As i said make a class method with return value of the score and access it everywhere you want.

Comment: sorry for earlier did almost everything like you said :)

Answer (score 0):

In your GameLostScene.h

```
@interface GameOverScene : SKScene
@property NSInteger *score;
@end
```

In your GameScene.m

```
#import gameLostScene.h
@interface gameScene ()<SKPhysicsContactDelegate>//If you using physics.
@property NSInteger score;
@end

-(void) gameLost {
    gameLostScene.score = self.score;
    SKScene *nextScene = [[GameLostScene alloc] initWithSize:self.size ];
    SKTransition *doors = [ SKTransition fadeWithDuration:1.0];
    [self.view presentScene:nextScene transition:doors];
}
```

Comment: GameLostScene.score = self.score; I can't access score property in GameLostScene. "property 'score' not found on object of type 'GameLostScene'

Comment: do you forgot #import gameLostScene.h in gameScene.m?

Comment: I think that he doesn't set the property score but ivar, so he has no setter right now. But he already solved this with class method i posted above so it is not actual for him anyway.

Comment: Then you should probably edit your answer because its incomplete Valar.